# My setter can get parameters,but actually can't?

Tags: c++, oop, setter

So i am making some kind of registry that stores people's informations.
My problem is that i have a class which has multiple setters and getters for a person(first name, birth date, birht place, etc.).
And when i try to read the informations in from a text file, i can't give the setters the parameters i got from the file.

I made a scratch file where i am trying to figure out the problem, but i can't really get anywhere. The loop doesn't matter, if the thing i am trying to do  is not in a loop and there is only one line in the file, the problem remains the same

```
int main(){
    std::string firstName;
    std::string lastName;
    std::string phoneNumber;
    std::string birthPlace;
    std::string birthDate;
    std::string Profession;

     Contacts newContact = Contacts();


    std::ifstream savedContacts("ContactList.txt");

    do{
        std::getline(savedContacts, firstName, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, lastName, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, phoneNumber, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, birthPlace, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, birthDate, ';');
        std::getline(savedContacts, Profession, ';');
 /* 
 in this case, this setter doesn't work,
 it doesn't get the string stored in firstName,after this,the program 
 crashes
 */
        newContact.setFirstname(firstName);
        std::cout<<newContact.getFirstname();

/*
and just to make sure that the reading of the file was successful
if i print out one of these strings, like this, it works perfectly 
*/
 std::cout<<firstName;
    }while(std::getline(savedContacts, firstName));
```

the funny thing is that, if i do this:
    newContact.setFirstname("Karen");
then the setter works perfectly and also my getter

this is how my setters and getters looklike in my Contacts class

```
    std::string Contacts::setFirstname(std::string firstName) {
    this->firstName = firstName;
}

std::string Contacts::getFirstname() {
    return firstName;
}
```

And this is inside the txt file:

```
John;Wick;1800181819;Paris;11.09.1990;Plumber;
Anthony;Joshua;192918180;Manchester;10.08.1994;Teacher;
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required her please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Several issues here:
std::string Contacts::setFirstname(std::string firstName) {
    this->firstName = firstName;
}

// Don't return a copy. Setters will usually only *set*
// If you WANT to return the value, you should NOT return a copy
// but a reference or a const reference
// You are copying AGAIN for the argument; take a const reference
// And probably avoid a copy
// Change parameter name and you could spare the this->
// and return a value; you declared a return type but no return statement
// Which means the code you posted doesn't compile
const std::string& Contacts::setFirstname(const std::string& newFirstName) 
{
    firstName = newFirstName;
    return firstName;
}

// Same here, return const reference and let the caller copy only if needed
// And make the getter const so it can work with const Contact
const std::string& Contacts::getFirstname() const {
    return firstName;
}
```

Also, about your problem, most likely is in the code that's calling setFirstName. Which you didn't provide. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)